# PHPStorm syntax highlighting showing false errors

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

For some time, PHPStorm 6 is behaving strangely: it keeps syntax errors displayed even when they're fixed.

The only way to clear them is to Cut and Paste.

Before C/P:

[image: Before Copy/Paste]

After C/P:

[image: After Copy Paste]

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Can't you update to PhpStrom 8? The Version 6 is pretty old and this might be an old bug which is already fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I don't want to pay for features I don't use, without even being sure it fixes that bug... What's more, that bug wasn't there some months ago with the same version.

Comment: You could always try the EAP for v8.

Comment: But how should we suppose to help you with such a bug if you are not willing to update. You might want to open an issue on the Jetbrain issue tracker, but I doubt that they will provide a fix for an old version.

Comment: might be a long shot, but what if you remove that last comma in your array? It shouldn't be there anyway. The one after `46 => 15,`

Comment: I didn't know SO only allowed question about latest versions... Anyway if noone has no idea I will try with EAPv8 or disabling plugins one by one.

Comment: @Ronnie: beside the fact that the bug is also appearing in other contexts, trailing commas are allowed in PHP arrays.

Comment: I understand that, but the syntax highlighter might not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems PHPStorm indexes are broken (as you have to cut/paste to get errors disappear). Please try invalidating caches (File/invalidate caches, restart). Does it help? if it doesn't, please contact PHPStorm support

Comment: And I saved 47€ not upgrading to V8 - but such a good support makes me want to.

Comment: Thank you for tip.